# (UFT) Method not working anymore after IE version update

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, hp-uft

I've run into some trouble lately after I've upgraded my Internet Explorer to IE 11 (IE version 11.0.9600.18537IS to be precise).
I'm running UFT version 12.02.

This method was working in previous IE versions but doesn't in IE 11 (bear in mind the text you'll see in quotation marks is in french but it corresponds to the text you get when you want to save a web page in a french Internet Explorer) :

```
Browser("WS E-Bill - Test").Dialog("Enregistrer la page Web").WinEdit("Nom du fichier :").Set g_strExecFileName
```

Comment: `Method not working`... elaborate.

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: The error isn't a message or something like that. After this method, the program tries to find the file that was supposed to be saved, and enters an infinite loop because it isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes UFT has issues with `.Set` in IE's Save As dialogs.  Try using `.Type` instead.  You'll need to be sure that the window has focus at the time.

Comment: Thank you Dave, i'll try your solution.